# Jupyter not running from Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Good day all

I've set up a VM using google cloud for hosting a Jupyter Hub server.

I have allowed both HTTP and HTTPS traffic. I have already set up a firewall to allow port 8888 with IP ranges 0.0.0.0/0. I have made the external IP address static (also tried ephemeral).

When running the command "jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser &" the Jupyter notebook starts up successfully with the following:

```
[I 09:51:49.924 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.1 is running at:
[I 09:51:49.924 NotebookApp] http://virtualpcname:8888/?token=xxxxx
[I 09:51:49.924 NotebookApp]  or http://localip:8888/?token=xxxxx
[I 09:51:49.924 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmatio
n).
[C 09:51:49.927 NotebookApp] 
    
    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///virtualmachinepath/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-28710-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://virtualpcname:8888/?token=xxxx
     or http://localip:8888/?token=xxxx
```

I then use the following format for the broweser:
http://STATIC_EXTERNAL_IP:8888/?token=xxxx

In the end I cannot connect to the server and get the classic "This site cannot be reached. Connection timed out"

I have also added exceptions for inbound and outbound connections directly to the Windows firewall for port 8888, turned off Firewall and still no luck

It seems like the access is restricted or blocked. How would I get around this? I have also tried on two separate PC's

Answer (score 0):

I took a n1-standard-8 (8 vCPUs, 30 GB memory) machine with 2 x NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPUs. The image was ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20200807 from GCP public image list. I allowed 5000 Ingress port for source filters (IP ranges) 0.0.0.0/0 in firewall default network. I followed [public doc](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52) to install the  Jupyter Notebook on Google Cloud Platform. After installation according to the [linked doc](https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52) I ran the below command:

**jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=5000**

and browsed the external static ip like this http://External_IP:5000/ and I was successful. From my observation we need to allow the port in firewall carefully to access the service where the service is running.